# How to repeat table horizontally using Aspose word

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspose.words

I am using ExecuteWithRegions(myDataSet) method of Aspose word for .NET for Mailmerge in my ASP.NET MVC application.
I have to create a pdf document with data coming from database like shown below
[image: documentHorizontal]

But when i use TableStart:DataTableName syntax it creates the Tables vertically as shown below
[image]

i have used the below syntax in my word file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, there is no way to repeat table horizontally using Mail Merge feature. However, you can try using LINQ Reporting Engine to grow the table horizontally. Please see Aspose.Words documentation to learn how to achieve this:
https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/outputting-sequential-data/#working-with-table-column-data-bands